# How to identify the last index of foreach loop using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**This is my each function in this how can i identify the last index of the each loop**

```
var mailtest = '';
$.each(data.getEmail, function (i) {
    $.each(data.getEmail[i], function (key, val) {
        if(key == 'personal_email'){
            mailtest += val+';';
        }
    });
});
alert(mailtest);
```

Because I am getting output like this, In this I dont want **;** in last

Output :

```
test@gmail.com; test1@gmail.com; test2@gmail.com; test3@gmail.com;
```

Output I want :

```
test@gmail.com; test1@gmail.com; test2@gmail.com; test3@gmail.com
```

Comment: `i == data.getEmail.length - 1`

Comment: Why dont you use `join()` instead

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz can you please post as a answer

Comment: let me check it sir @j08691

Comment: There's no need for an answer, this is basic JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: If you had posted an example of the data, we could likely find a `map` that would get it in one line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple:

```
var mailtest = [];
$.each(data.getEmail, function (i) {
  $.each(data.getEmail[i], function (key, val) {
    if(key == 'personal_email'){
        mailtest.push(val)
    }
  });
});
console.log(mailtest.join(";"));
```

NOTE: If you had posted an example of the data, we could likely find a map that would get it in one line

Answer (score 2):

You could use `join()`.
 as long as you data structure is similar to this one

```js
var data = {
 getEmail: [
  {
   personal_email: 'test@gmail.com'
  },
  {
   personal_email: 'test1@gmail.com'
  },
  {
   personal_email: 'test2@gmail.com'
  },
 ]
}
console.log(
  data.getEmail.map(a=>a.personal_email).join("; ")
)
```

Comment: You could use join regardless of structure ;)

Comment: Thank You for you time sir, I will make a note of this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/)'s methods, here's how:

1. filter ([`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) the array first
2. then map it ([`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map))
3. finally join it into a string ([`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join))

Here's the code:

```js
var mailtest = '';
$.each(data.getEmail, function(i) {
  mailtest += data.getEmail[i]
    .filter((key, val) => (key == 'personal_email'))
    .map((key, val) => val)
    .join(';')
});
alert(mailtest);
```

---

Or you could just remove the last character of your string:

```
mailtest.substring(0, mailtest.length - 1);
```

Comment: Thank You for you time sir, I will make a note of this solution.

Comment: I am not convinced that is valid either. You are concatenating each round. If there are more, then you will get `xxx@yyy.com;xxx@yyy.com;xxx@yyy.comxxx@yyy.com;xxx@yyy.com`